# Can I not append a .text from beautiful soup to a python DataFrame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to loop through a list of URLs to pull specific text from a website using requests.get() and beautiful soup. The URLs come back fine and I can also print the text I am looking for (phone numbers) and it works fine but I receive a `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid` when attempting to append to the dataframe that was previously created with empty [].

````
    try:
        response = requests.get(f"https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms={sc_df['Business Name'][i]}&geo_location_terms={sc_df['City'][i]}+{sc_df['State'][i]}")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        test = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'info'}).find('div', attrs = {'class':'phones phone primary'})

        if test is not None:
            text = test.text
            print(str(text))

            new_number_df['Business Name'].append(sc_df['Business Name'][i])
            new_number_df['Phone'].append(text)
        else:
            test = None
            print(test)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
        raise SystemExit(e)```
````

Answer (score 0):

as your error says, you

> cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>

so you need to convert your addition to a pandas.Series object and then append it, as follows:

```
new_number_df['Phone'].append(pandas.Series([text]))
```

hope this solved your problem!

Comment: Thank you for your time, I wonder how long I will be following that up with "Sorry, I am still new to all this".  This (pd.Series()) allowed the line to run all the way through with no errors but upon inspecting the dataframe, it is returned empty.

Comment: Your original question was about appending a string to a dataframe column. If that problem was solved and another arose please accept the satisfactory answer and ask a new question providing the necessary information (for example a sample of you dataframe, which was irrelevant for this question but absolutely crucial for reproducing the new problem) and someone will help you. This allows the platform to be useful to others, as each question and title solves a problem which could arise in other people's code.